# Regex match everything between special tag

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string that I need to parse and get the values of anything inside the defined `\$` tags

for example, the string

```
The following math equation: \$f(x) = x^2\$ is the same as \$g(x) = x^(4/2) \$
```

I want to parse whatever is in between the `\$` tags, so that the result will contain both equations

```
'f(x) = x^2'
'g(x) = x^(4/2) '
```

I tried something like `re.compile(r'\\\$(.)*\\$')` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it, just missing a backslash and a question mark (so it stops as soon as it finds the second `\$` and doesn't match the longest string possible): `r'\\\$(.*?)\\\$'`

```
>>> pattern = r'\\\$(.*?)\\\$'
>>> data = "The following math equation: \$f(x) = x^2\$ is the same as \$g(x) = x^(4/2) \$"
>>> re.findall(pattern, data)
['f(x) = x^2', 'g(x) = x^(4/2) ']
```

Comment: Great! thank you. Can this be modified so that escaped `\$` are not matched? Like `\\$`

Comment: What do you mean? It's not in the output.

Comment: If the data is ` \\$ f(x)=1\$` then it shouldn't match because there is a double slash in the beginning

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. It's `(?<!\\)\\\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\\\$`

Answer (score 1):

That regex can fit:

```
/\\\$.{0,}\\\$/g
```

`/` - begin
`\\\$` - escaped: \$
`.` - any character between
`{0,}` - at least 0 chars (any number of chars, actually)
`\\\$` - escaped: \$
`/` - end
`g` - global search

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import re
regex = r'\\\$(.*)\\\$'
r = re.compile(regex)
print r.match("\$f(x) = x^2\$").group(1)
print r.match("\$g(x) = x^(4/2) \$").group(1)
```

Comment: That doesn't really work with the given example though, the `.*` is too greedy and gets both equations and the rest of the text in between.